# OAuth for office365 creating infinit loop of cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, c#-4.0, oauth, office365

I am creating a multi-tenant webapp with Oauth. I created the Azure App and given the REPLY URL as similar to my web app URL. When i tried to login first time it worked perfectly and re-directed to my website finely. After that i cleared my cookies and sessions. Now i tried to login using office365 account causing infinit loop of creating multiple cookies. Please check the screenshot for more info.

Can anybody know what will be the problem?[image]

```
        public void SignIn()
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
    public void SignOut()
    {
        // Remove all cache entries for this user and send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.
        string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }




    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                Authority = SettingsHelper.Authority,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {

                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;

                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret);
                        String UserObjectId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(UserObjectId));

                        authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, SettingsHelper.AADGraphResourceId);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },


                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                        // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                        // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                        string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        // Suppress the exception if you don't want to see the error
                        context.HandleResponse();

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                }

            });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for better understand your issue>?

Comment: i am using the code from below github. https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant . The same code works fine when i executed from localhost:24488 but not working when i hosted in Azure. I don't know what will be the exact reason.